# Postgres jsonb 'NOT contains' operator

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I'm experimenting with postgres `jsonb` column types, and so far so good. 
One common query I'm using is like this:

```
select count(*) from jsonbtest WHERE attributes @> '{"City":"Mesa"}';
```

How do I reverse that? Is there a different operator or is it simply used as

```
select count(*) from jsonbtest WHERE NOT attributes @> '{"City":"Mesa"}';
```

Comment: No, there is no dedicated operator for that. What's wrong with `NOT`?

Comment: @redneb The problem is that `NOT` simply doesn't work. Using the `attributes->>'City' <> 'Mesa'` formulation also doesn't work.

Comment: @eykanal `NOT` [works pretty well](http://rextester.com/TMGVQZ95259).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Two way, you can test any json(b) value

- the `->>` operator extract value as text. But this operation slow, if you will use the value only test
- the `@>` operator test any json(b) contain any json(b). This is a quick but you are not tested NOT option.

Simply and quick way:

```
NOT (attribute @> '{"City":"Mesa"}'::jsonb)
```

I've change `attribute->>'City' <> 'Mesa'` to `NOT (attribute @> '{"City":"Mesa"}'::jsonb)` and my ~2.000.000 rows query result time changed 45secs to 25secs.

Comment: The frustrating thing is that if you've added a nice `USING GIN(attribute)` index, negating the @> contains operator suddenly stops using that index.

Comment: NOT doesn't covers situation when you have attribute but this attribute equals NULL

Comment: @DmitryChirkin simpe test. null valued object:
SELECT NOT('{"City":null}'::jsonb @> '{"City":"Mesa"}'::jsonb);
returns as true
alternatively test. not contain attribute:
SELECT NOT('{"Another Attribute":"Mesa"}'::jsonb @> '{"City":"Mesa"}'::jsonb)
returns true
i think there is no problem

Comment: @nessur You can create the GIN index with jsonb_ops.
e.g:

CREATE INDEX idx_my_index_jsonb_data_with_ops ON my_table USING GIN (attribut jsonb_ops);
You can use this link for options:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html

Answer (score 12):

This can be achieved with several conditions. 
It's not elegant but I didn't find another way to do so.

So, first, get every row which simple don't have 'City' attribute and then add 'OR' condition to check for correct field value.

```sql
select count(*) from jsonbtest where 
  NOT(attributes ? 'City') 
  OR (attributes ? 'City') is NULL -- this is required if attributes can be null
  OR (attributes->>'City' != 'Mesa'))
```

Comment: This helped me a lot... I couldn't find anyting about on this use case on the PgSQL site. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

---contains specific key (City), does not contain value ('"Mesa"').

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jsonbtest  WHERE NOT (attributes  -> 'City'  @> '"Mesa"');
```

---does not contain specific key value pair: {"City":"Mesa"}

```
SELECT count(*) FROM jsonbtest  WHERE  NOT (attributes  @> '{"City":"Mesa"}')
```

Since attributes key can be others except *City*. So these two queries are different!

Answer (score -3):

You can use the operator `<@` this will search where 'City' is not 'Mesa'

```
select count(*) from jsonbtest WHERE attributes <@ '{"City":"Mesa"}';
```

Comment: That would be the same as ```select count(*) from jsonbtest WHERE '{"City":"Mesa"}' @> attributes;```, checking if ```{"City": "Mesa"}``` contains ```attributes``` which is not the same.